# How to find hidden file/&folder with cmd command, whose name I have forgotten?

Tags: file, cmd

I've hidden a folder with cmd command using attrib, but I forgot the name of that folder. I know the path.
Now, How I can find that hidden folder?

Comment: `dir /ad /ah` to show hidden (`/ah`) folders (`/ad`) only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of hidden folders using this command

```
dir /a    To list all files and folders.
dir /a:d   for all directories.
dir /a:h  for all hidden files.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write these following codes
if you want to see only hidden folders and files type
dir /a:h

if you want to see only folders not hidden then type
dir /a:d

if you want to see folders, files and also hidden items then type
dir /a